# How to hand over a struct type to a generic stack

Tags: c, generics

I have to hand over a freefunction for complex datatypes on a generic stack.

My function in the test version:

```
void freefn(time *element) {
    printf("%s\n",element->day);
    free(element->day);
}
```

In main:

```
GenStackNew(&dates,sizeof(time),freefn);
```

In my API:

```
if(s->freefn!=NULL) {
        for (i = 0; i < s->allocLength; i++) {
            s->freefn((char *) s->elems + i * s->elemSize);
        }
    }
```

If I compile it this way the compiler says:

> incompatible pointer types passing '`void (time *)`' to
>         parameter of type '`void (*)(void *)`'. When I hand over the element as a `void *` and then cast it to `struct time*` it frees the wrong memory.

Edit:
if I cast it this way:

```
void freefn(void *element) {
    time *telement = (time*)element;
    printf("%s\n",telement->day);
    free(telement->day);
}
```

this error message appears:
./gentest3': free(): invalid pointer: 0x0000000000400bf7

Comment: The incorrect pointer type is obviously a problem. You're sending a `char*` to a function expecting a `time*`. Beyond that, if `allocLength` is the length in *bytes* of allocated memory sequence, your loop is wrong as well. Since you didn't post a [minimal, **complete**, and  verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), wild guess are the best you can hope for at this point.

Comment: The proto type for `GenStackNew` seems to expect a `void (*)(void *)` but you pass `void (*)(time *)`. Besides that - how do you notice that it frees the wrong memory? How do you allocate memory? How does the code look in that case?

Comment: I edited the answer to the questions